# How to interpret a PeopleSoft web server load test

Tags: load-testing, peoplesoft, blazemeter

I was conducting a load test on a PeopleSoft client's web server over the weekend. In all scenarios except the baseline scenario, I had a spike in errors around 4 mins into the test. In all scenarios the hits/s were different at this time.

Additionally, the response time for the landing page was between 35 and 65 seconds, even though the response time when testing the site in the browser was < 10s when I tested during the peak of the load test.

What could be causing the long response time and the error spike at 4 minutes?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Without knowing more about your application, this is pure guessing

Answer (score 1):

The reasons could be numerous and the only way to identify the root cause is using monitoring.

Ask around, it might be the case you have an [APM tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/getting-the-full-application-picture-with-blazemeter-and-apm-integration) installed and configured so you would be able to correlate the "spikes" and other JMeter metrics with the data from the APM tool.

If there is no APM integration available you could implement it yourself using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/).

It also makes sense to monitor your JMeter load generators health as well as the fluctuations in the response times might be caused by lack of resources or on JMeter side or not following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)